# What type of traversal should be used to find the sum of a binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, depth-first-search, tree-traversal

The following question appeared on a test my instructor gave a couple of years ago.  He provided an answer, but did not provide a satisfactory explanation.  I have googled this topic, but I didn't find much.  I was hoping that the community could help me understand this concept.

> In order to find the sum of all of the integers in a binary tree, what type of traversal would be used?
>   (A) breadth-first
>   (B) depth-first in-order
>   (C) depth-first post-order
>   (D) depth-first pre-order

My instructor says that the answer is (C) depth-first post-order, but I don't understand why.  It seems like they would all work.  I would appreciate any insight that you might have.

Thanks.

Edit:
I finally figured how why my instructor thought the answer was (C).

If you were to write a sum function with the addition all in a single statement such as:

```
    int addup(Node n)
    {
        if (n == nil) return 0;
        return addup(n.left) + n.value + addup(n.right);
    }
```

The traversal would be post-order regardless of the order of the terms in the sum.  This is because the two functions are evaluated first before the addition occurs.  It is, however, trivial to force a pre-order or in-order traversal as Keith Randall showed in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any traversal order would work, as sum is associative and symmetric.  For example, depth-first in-order:

```
int addup(Node n) {
    if (n == nil) return 0;
    int sum = addup(n.left);
    sum += n.value;
    sum += addup(n.right);
    return sum;
}
```

All the traversals admit an easy sum implementation.